# html autocomplete select box click functionality not working in windows 8 touch device

Tags: jquery, jsp, select, autocomplete, touch

I have one autocomplete select box there in the jsp page which is working as expected in the usual flow. No exceptions there in any of the desktop version.

But the problem over here is when users trying to access the same from a touch device, they gets the drop downs loaded in it at the time of autocomplete works. But when selecting the value it does not populate the field.

I believe the problem here is the click() function is not working when the user trying to access it from a touch device. Is there anyone have a solution where we can call the same click() function when touch event calls.